# Why doesn't source work when I call bash -c

Tags: bash, shell, quoting

I want to run a command that sources a script to take on some env. variables before executing, without sourcing them in my current shell.

test.env

```
export test=1
```

None of these commands echo the env. variable:

a) Shouldn't this work? Aren't I just executing these commands in a new shell and returning the output?

```
$ bash -c "source test.env && echo $test"
```

b) Here I execute test.env and try to run echo $test in the same process using exec.

```
$ bash -c "./test.env && exec echo $test"
```

c) Lastly I just tried this since it was a possible permutation. But it executes test.env and the echo command as separate processes.

```
$ bash -c "./test.env && echo $test"
```

And how can I get this to work where the env. variables are sourced before the 2nd command is executed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must escape dollar sign `$` in your first command, otherwise `bash` will expand it before your command executed:

```
$ bash -c "source test.env && echo \$test"
```

Or you should use single quote instead of double quote:

```
$ bash -c 'source test.env && echo $test'
```

Comment: it's the simplest errors that are the most stumping

Answer (score 1):

If the goal is only to handle setting `ENV` before running a process and avoiding affecting the current shell then `exec`ing the `bash` executable might not be the most efficient way to go about it.

```
( . /dev/fd/4 && echo "$i" ) 4<<\SCRIPT
    i='i is set here in the subshell'
#END
SCRIPT

echo ${i?but i isnt set here because it was set in the subshell}
```

#### OUTPUT

```
i is set here in the subshell
sh: line 5: i: but i isnt set here because it was set in the subshell
```

You can of course substitute the link to the heredoc's file-descriptor with a regular file - I just used it to demonstrate it.

But if you *do* `exec` an outside process - such as `bash` or any other - rather than a shell builtin then you don't need the subshell.

```
one=1 two=2 \
    bash -c 'echo "${cmd=This is command #}$one" 
             echo "${cmd}$two"'
echo "${one?this var was only set for the execed ENV}"
```

#### OUTPUT

```
This is command #1
This is command #2
sh: line 2: one: this var was only set for the execed ENV
```

And if that outside process *is* `bash` or any other shell conforming to the POSIX standard of accepting `-s`tdin as default, you can just write your script directly to a `|pipe` file...

```
{ echo PS1=
  echo 'echo "$PS1"'
  cat /etc/skel/.bashrc
  echo 'echo "$PS1"'
} | bash
echo "${PS1:?unset here again}"
```

#### OUTPUT

```
#blank line from first echo
[\u@\h \W]\$
sh: line 7: PS1: unset here again
```

Answer (score 0):

As written, the shell is expanding `$test` before it is passed to your command. You can stop this from happening by using a `'`  instead of `"`.

```
bash -c 'source test.env && echo $test'
```